# jQuery won't finish submitting and adds parameters in address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

**Edit: Updated jsFiddle link. See second sentence.**

I am making a website that recommends subreddits for you by using the subreddit API. 
The project is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fw8jr4n8/5/). The site is best viewed in a maximised browser window at the moment as I'm not finished with the front-end.

It works by getting the inputted subreddits from the form, puts it in an array (using .serializeArray()). I also use the same function to get the omitted subreddits from the second form, too. It then gets the values and puts them together in a string. The final result (in the api variable) should be something like http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/AskReddit,CasualConversation,?omit=SkypePals, depending on the inputted subreddits.
After this it simply uses the api variable as a parameter for the getJSON() function, whic returns the JSON response from Reddit into the json variable. Then I use each() to iterate over the JSON response so that the recommended subreddits are put into the right column (beneath recommendations).

I've spent hours trying to fix this and it still doesn't work. When clicking the submit button it refreshes the page and adds parameters into the address bar with the input of the form inputs. I don't know why this is.

Any help to fix this and avoid this in the future would be greatly appreciated. I can't get my head around this haha. I can't find anything that helps through searching either. I don't exactly know what the name of this issue is.

Apparently I am required to also provide code in this post as I linked to jsFiddle. I think my Javascript is most relevant so I'll provide that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var api = "http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/";
    var json;
    var redditBaseLink = "http://www.reddit.com/r/";
    var srLink;
    var srArray;
    var srString = '';
    var omitArray, omitString;

    $(".srInputForm").submit(function (event) {
        srArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(srArray, function (i, field) {
            srString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(srString, "?omit=");

        $.each(omitArray, function (i, field) {
            omitString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(omitString);

        json = $.getJSON(api);

        $.each(json, function (i, response) {
            srLink = "";
            srLink = '<div class="recommendation">' + '<a href="' + redditBaseLink + response.sr_name + '/" target="_blank">' + response.sr_name + '</a></div>';

            $(srLink).hide().appendTo(".recommendationsCol").fadeIn('slow');
        });

        event.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: you want ajax submit - so that it will not submit the entire page..

Comment: ^ Hi. Not too sure what you mean by this? AFAIK it isn't submitting the whole page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your event.preventDefault, it should be

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Also, check the correct usage of $.getJSON, your $.each should be inside $.getJSON success callback.

For example

```
$.getJSON("ajax/test.json", function(data) {
    // $.each() here.
});
```

Comment: Hi. I've corrected both of these. Regardless, nothing changes. Please see the updated jsFiddle link in the OP.